# Skip GitHub hooks on push

Tags: git, github, pivotaltracker

We are looking for a way to disable a GitHub webhook from the command line when pushing a rebase to prevent duplicate entries in Pivotal Tracker.

Has anyone implemented this before?  It doesn't look like `git push --no-verify` will work as I believe the webhooks in GitHub are `post-receive`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're correct about your problem being the post-receive hook I don't think you'll be able to flag it off based on the git man page:

> **post-receive**
>
> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which happens when a git push is done on a local
>   repository. It executes on the
>   remote repository once after all the refs have been updated.
>
> This hook executes once for the receive operation. **It takes no arguments,** but gets the same information as the pre-receive hook does
>   on its standard
>   input.
>
> This hook does not affect the outcome of git-receive-pack, as it is called after the real work is done.
>
> This supersedes the post-update hook in that it gets both old and new values of all the refs in addition to their names.
>
> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for
>   the user.
>
> The default post-receive hook is empty, but there is a sample script post-receive-email provided in the contrib/hooks directory in
>   Git distribution,
>   which implements sending commit emails.

Here's one way you might be able to do this. In cases where you want to skip the post-receive hook, use a custom method you've defined in bash that:

1. Moves .git/hooks/post-receive to some other file name
2. Does your push
3. Moves .git/hooks/some_other_file_name back to .git/hooks/post-receive